# Memory leak when allocating Core Data managedobject that's passed between methods

Tags: core-data, ios4, xcode4

I'm having a memory leak in the following code. I got 87.5% of the memory leak before Instruments itself crashed. Maybe one of you can tell me what is wrong with this code. Do I need to be releasing anything in here? Thanks.

```
- (void)browseSSviewControllerDidFinish:(browseSSviewController *)controller {
<SNIP>
      MANAGED_OBJECT_1 = [self newFormatFromFormat:MANAGED_OBJECT_2];
<SNIP>
}

- (Format *)newFormatFromFormat:(Format *)formatToCopy {

    NSLog(@"making new format that's a copy");
    Format *thisNewFormat = [self newBlankFormat];
    [self updateFormat:thisNewFormat withNumbersFromFormat:formatToCopy];
    return thisNewFormat;
}

-(void)updateFormat:(Format *)formatToCopyTo withNumbersFromFormat:(Format *)formatToCopyFrom {
    NSLog(@"copying formats");
    formatToCopyTo.x = formatToCopyFrom.x;
    formatToCopyTo.y = formatToCopyFrom.y;
    formatToCopyTo.z = formatToCopyFrom.z;
    formatToCopyTo.a = formatToCopyFrom.a;
    formatToCopyTo.n = formatToCopyFrom.n;
    formatToCopyTo.u = formatToCopyFrom.u;
    formatToCopyTo.s = formatToCopyFrom.s;
}

- (Format *)newBlankFormat {

    NSLog(@"making new blank format");
    gfghfAppDelegate *del = (gfghfAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *MOC = del.managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *PSC = [MOC persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSManagedObjectModel *MOM = [PSC managedObjectModel];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[MOM entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Format"];
    Format *thisNewFormat = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:MOC]; 
    thisNewFormat.slot = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
    NSLog(@"slot = %@",thisNewFormat.slot);
    return thisNewFormat;
}
```

Here is the 87.5% of the leak that I was able to get out of my backtrace before Instruments crashed:

`+0xc7  calll                          DYLD-STUB$$objc_msgSend = 87.5%`

I didn't use mutableCopy to copy my MANAGED_OBJECTs because it just didn't work.

Comment: PS -- MANAGED_OBJECT_1 and MANAGED_OBJECT_2 are both instance variables - properties of the custom view controller object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the newBlankFormat:thisNewFormat method and used the "insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:" convenience method of NSEntityDescription (see "Creating, Initializing, and Saving a Managed Object" in the "Creating and Deleting Managed Objects" chapter of Apple's "Core Data Programming Guide").

I think my problem initially that I was using "NSManagedObject alloc" with "initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext", which does not make an auto-released object. It would leak even when I would release it myself from another method using a "release" later on the returned value using the instance variable that got the return value from this method. However, whether or not I put in a "retain" around the malloc, the release count wasn't being incremented I don't believe, since it's not a proper init function? I'm not sure why.

But I don't care because the following revision fixed the leak, and as it turns out, is what Apple recommended to use anyway (I think I was using the old code from an example project or something).

Here is the revision that appears to have fixed the leak, in the new version of the "newBlankFormat:thisNewFormat" function:

```
- (Format *)newBlankFormat:(Format *)thisNewFormat {
            NSLog(@"making new blank format");
            gfghfAppDelegate *del = (gfghfAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            NSManagedObjectContext *MOC = del.managedObjectContext;
            //[MOC reset]; don't do this, it will erase MANAGED_OBJECT_2
            thisNewFormat = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Format" inManagedObjectContext:MOC]; //this is much better than using the malloc variety
            thisNewFormat.slot = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
            NSLog(@"slot = %@",thisNewFormat.slot);
            return thisNewFormat;
}
```

Comment: This won't work actually because the [MOC Reset] clears MANAGED_OBJECT_2 out of the context. Editing that out to show how that could be fixed.

Comment: Also note: the auto-released object this creates crashed my app since run loops would end before another object could receive it in passed messages. Had to go back to the original method in the first question and add a release on "thisNewFormat" before it gets pointed at the newly alloc'd Format object to clear the leak, while also still creating an object that will get retained as it's passed around between various objects and methods.